# How to post json data using West Wind in VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro, westwind

There's a document from West Wind says you can post data using application/json format:

https://west-wind.com/webconnection/docs/_2110q21c9.htm

But when using it, actually it'll do a http get instead of post:

> DO wwhttp
>   oHTTP=CREATEOBJECT("wwHttp")
>   oHTTP.nHTTPPostMode = 8
>   oHttp.cContentType = "application/json" 
>   oHTTP.AddPostKey("name","somename")
>   lcURL = "https://mywebserver.com/" 
>   lcXML = oHTTP.HTTPGet(lcURL)

If using nHTTPPostMode = 1 or 2, the http request parameters are not correctly formatted as json. If I change to 4, it's using Get instead of Post again. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: You might get answers more quickly over on the West Wind forums: http://west-wind.com/wwThreads/default_frames.asp

Comment: Thanks, I'll post a question in West Wind forum.

Answer (score 1):

When you post JSON data you need to post a JSON **document** not key value pairs as you are doing in your example. Essentially you need to provide the full content - the entire JSON document as a string - that you're sending to the server (just like the example shows).

To post a JSON document looks like this:

```
DO wwHttp

oHTTP=CREATEOBJECT("wwHttp")
oHttp.cContentType = "application/json"

lcJson = "{ name: 'somename' }"
oHTTP.AddPostKey(lcJson)  && this sets the entire post buffer

lcURL = "https://mywebserver.com/" 
lcJson = oHTTP.HTTPGet(lcURL)
```

Using name value pairs only works with POST buffers for URLEncoded or Multipart documents - every other type of content is sent as raw data that you have to provide.

in version 6 and later you can also use the following simpler syntax to `.Post` data:

```
oHttp.cContentType = "application/json"
lcJson = oHttp.Post(lcUrl, lcJson)
```

If you want to create JSON documents under program control you can serialize data using the [wwJsonSerializer class](https://webconnection.west-wind.com/docs/_1wu18owba.htm) (also part of Client Tools). It can serialize from objects, arrays/collections and cursors.